# Master Page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I need to ask if I have master page that contain button as an example then I add new webform(default) and I assign that master page as default form master page.the question is can I change the text of the button in default page code?

Answer (score 4):

sure you can, it's either way...

you should see the video screencasts about MAster Pages, you will see how to accomplish that and much more!

> Video # 12 
>   [MasterPages](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-7024.aspx)
>   16 minutes, 2 seconds
>
> Video # 36
>   [How Do I: Work with Master Pages Declaratively and Programmatically](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-265.aspx)
>   29 minutes, 49 seconds
>
> Video # 37 
>   [How Do I: Handle Events in Master and Content Pages](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-266.aspx)
>   23 minutes, 26 seconds

Answer (score 1):

I would use a property on the master page to change the button, I think you can make it public but meh.

```
public String ButtonText { get { return button1.text; } set { button1.Text = value } }
```

Then on the default page, set the master type.

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/mymaster.master"  %>
```

Then on the default page you should be able to access by going through the property.

```
Master.ButtonText = "Hello, Master Page Button";
```

[Sorry, assuming C#]

Comment: This is a good approach, since it encapsulates the inner implementation of the master pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the MasterType directive on your default page

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master1.master" %>
```

then you can call methods and properties on the master page in the code-behind:

```
MyButton.Text = "New text";
```

For more information see 
[ASP.Net 2.0 - Master Pages: Tips, Tricks, and Traps](http://www.odetocode.com/articles/450.aspx)